# Unsupported infrared (IR) remote in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, remote-control, lirc

I have an infrared eye and remote, named IR 507 and RC105, which only has Windows-support (drives avaliable on http://edio-rc105-ir507.driver.soft32download.com/). Seems I only use Ubuntu nowadays, I wonder if I can make this work at all with Linux.

I have downloaded the Lirc tarbox but this not include drivers for mentioned remote. My experience of Linux is that most things will work in any way, such as if I manually "mapping" the remote's buttons with the infrared eye.

My questions to the community are therefore,

1. How do I connect a unsupported IR-receiver to the system?
2. How do I "learn" the receiver to understand different buttons from
   the remote?
3. Is there any other preferable way to make it work?
4. I thought about Wine, but will this make the remote implemented in system-commands?

[This is the PDF Manual.](http://www.qstarz.com/download/RC-Q105_V1.1_English_Manual.pdf) I use an Latitude D630 32-bit with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you refer to [this](http://www.qstarz.com/download/RC-Q105_V1.1_English_Manual.pdf) pdf document?